# SVG: fixed height fluid width

Tags: html, css, svg

So I have this SVG that I want to be responsive. It works fine when I use `preserveAspectRatio="none"`, but turns out really ugly and pixelated when I'm resizing the browser window. How can I accomplish a fluid width and fixed height?

```
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 663 38" height="38" preserveAspectRatio="none">
```

See full example here: https://codepen.io/billy_sengsey/pen/LOmXXQ

Before resizing:
[image: before resizing]

After resizing:

[image: after resizing]

Comment: it's working as it should be, what's the issue here.? please explain yourself.!

Comment: @weBer yeah, it works, but as you can see on the last image it looks pixelated. So I'm wondering if anyone has a fix for that.

Comment: Looks like sub-pixel rendering. The stroke is only 1px wide but is at an angle and the browser has to round up/down.